# Read only access to SQL Server's Database through Connection String in web.config

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to provide read only access to a SQL Server's DB through Connection String in the web.config file from a .Net Application?

Comment: Use a user name that has only read permissions on the DB.

Comment: No, not along the lines of `readonly=true`. You would instead provide credentials for a user with no write permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i did as said by Uwe Keim. Created a user name that has only read permissions on the DB. No other way to restrict from Connection String.